# Find values of coeffients when minima is given

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a function 
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)=a x+b y,
\end{align*} where $a$ and $b $ are constants. This function has minima at points $(1,4)$ and $(4,1)$. We need to find the values of constants subject to the following constraints:
\begin{align*}
x+y\ge5,\quad x+2y\le20,\quad x,y\ge0.
\end{align*}
I tried to solve using Lagrangian methods. I am not able to find the correct solution. Help needed.

Answer (score 0):

Notice: for each $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have linear programming problem. If you represent de polygon $R$, $(1,4)$ and $(4,1)$ are point of a edge, so all points of the edge are minimun for $f$.

Due to $f(4,1) = f(1,4) = 4a+b=a+4b$ we have $a=b$.

$(10,0)$ is a vertex of $R$, so $f(0,5)\leq f(0,10) \Rightarrow 5a\leq 10a \Rightarrow a\geq 0$.

You only need $f(0,5)=f(5,0)=f(1,4)=f(4,1)$ to be smaller than $f(0,20)$ and $f(0,10)$, and get it for each $a\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If a linear function on the shaded region attains its minimum at the red points...

[image]

it means that any point on the segment joining $(5,0)$ and $(0,5)$ is a point of minimum, since the red points are not vertices of the shaded region (the minima of a convex function on a convex set are attained at the boundary). It follows that $a=b$ and $a\geq 0$.